# How can we use mean filter as adaptive one?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

When we have noise in background area then we can use mean filter to remove noise since there is no sharp features for our processing. when we do the noise removal for the image region which contains edges (finer details).This region completely blur and we miss the finer details.

**Can we apply a filter such that which will do heavy blurring  on the flat area(background of image) and apply very little blur in feature regions?**
One more,

**Do we have an implementation of this  filter in opencv?**

Comment: See bilateral filter. https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga9d7064d478c95d60003cf839430737ed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very good adaptive filter is the bilateral filter. It applies a Gaussian filter for smoothing, but additionally weighs each sample by how similar it is to the central value under the mask. Thus, it effectively only averages over pixels that have a similar value. In a flat region, all pixels have a similar value, hence it averages over the full kernel. Near an edge, only pixels up to the edge have a similar value, hence it averages only over the pixels up to the edge.

In OpenCV this is implemented in [`cv::bilateralFilter`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga9d7064d478c95d60003cf839430737ed).

Answer (score 1):

Look for Median filter. Example:

[image]

Available in OpenCV [doc here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#median-filtering)

Comment: This one works better in removing salt and pepper noise but not for gaussian noise. For the gaussian noise, it will fail.

Comment: @coder_v_3.0: That’s a misconception. The median filter works just fine for Gaussian noise because the median is a good estimator of the average value. In fact, for Gaussian distributed data, the mean and median are identical given a large sample size.

Comment: @coder_v_3.0: I agree with Cris, the median filter is not too bad at edge-preserving denoising. (The image chosen for illustration is a little irrelevant.)

Comment: The mean filter is better than the median filter when we need to remove  Gaussian noise. Thanks, @Cris, I understood what you told above.

Comment: The biggest problem is mostly that the original question doesn't provide any example of the noise to be removed other than "noise removal for the image region which contains edges (finer details)", which can be pretty much anything depending on context...

Comment: doc link is deprecated.